# How to make my controls to be in the middle?

Tags: asp.net

this is my first asp.net site that i write 
I want to have simple form with 5 textbox line that the user will be able to write in 
and one button that the user will be able to press when he finish his data input.

Each textbox that i adding i automaticly jump to the left side of the form.

How can i control the place that it will will be shown ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block elements can be aligned by setting the left and right margins to *auto*. Setting the left and right margins to auto specifies that they should split the available margin equally. The result is a centered element:

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

---

Read about [Horizontal Alignment](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp).

Answer (score 2):

You should probably do that with a simple css script.
You can add a css page/script to your solution. And then add that in the header of the page. But you could also use something like this on the top of your .asp page :

```
<style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
        position:absolute;
        left:12%
        top: 50px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the textboxes into a div with centered text:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to understant web development, you need to know basic concepts of HTML and CSS.
I would recommend you to learn some HTML and CSS first, you can google it or go to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/).

Everything will be easier.

Comment: Good comment, but it should be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Like Chinese Proverb (I think) says:
"Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime." 
I understand that this seems like a comment, but this is an answer.